# Inconsistency of frame size when device rotates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, rotation

If I test my app on the **emulator**, rotate the view and check rotation and view.frame of my view controller I get the following:

```
Landscape: (0.0,0.0,1024.0,768.0)
Portrait: (0.0,0.0,768.0,1024.0)
```

But if I test it on the **device** I get:

```
Landscape: (0.0,0.0,768.0,1024.0)
Portrait: (0.0,0.0,768.0,1024.0)
```

I.e. on the emulator the width and height switches according to rotation but on the device it doesn't. Is this a known behaviour? I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 5 to test this.

Comment: Just check the interface orientation lock on the iPad

Comment: The interface lock is off. Which makes sense since if it's locked, the device wouldn't broadcast a rotation change at all, right?

Comment: I have faced this situation, are you sure in the device orientation is changing? Is the project enabled for all the orientations? Just a check on the basics.. IMHO they must have been set wrongly

Comment: Yes the device rotation is definitely changing and project is enabled for orientations Portrait, LS left, LS right.